# maximum # characters in CURL submission to Ontotext GraphDB?

Tags: r, curl, sparql, graphdb

I have some SPARQL queries that are over 5000 charters.  When they are submitted to GraphDB via CURL (specifically `httr::GET` in `R`), they don't appear on the query monitor screen, and the (immediate) CURL response is empty.

**Is there a way to allow the submission of longer SPARQL queries over CURL to GraphDB?**  These long queries do work when I submit them directly to the web interface.

*I haven't figured out the exact cutoff yet.  My longest working query so far is 4779 characters.*

*I'm working through opportunities to make the queries shorter, like minimizing whitespace, shorter variable names, and possibly overall refactoring.*

Comment: did you try a `POST` request instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This highly depends on what curl request you are using, precisely. If you are storing data in the body, there should be no problem.

Generally, though, I'd recommend going with `POST` requests for anything sizeable, as suggested in the comments. This avoids issues where the response size is limited by the client.

Comment: I just had to set aside the time to relearn the differences between POST and GET.  Thanks, AKSW and Radostin.